# Amazon AWS IAM Policy Issue

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I have a bucket called "facontroltest",  created a User on IAM with a custom policy. When i access to a bucket that isn't the bucket of the policy the API perfoms all the actions. But i need that the user on the api can access just for that bucket.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:GetBucketLocation",
                "s3:ListBucketMultipartUploads"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::facontroltest",
            "Condition": {}
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:AbortMultipartUpload",
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:DeleteObjectVersion",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetObjectAcl",
                "s3:GetObjectVersion",
                "s3:GetObjectVersionAcl",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl",
                "s3:PutObjectAclVersion"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::facontroltest/*",
            "Condition": {}
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {}
        }
    ]
}
```

My PHP Code:

```
$Credentials = new Credentials('key_user', 'secret_key');

$AmazonService = new S3Client([ 'version' => 'latest', 'region' => 'us-west-2', 'credentials' => $Credentials]);

$result = $AmazonService->getObject(array(
    'Bucket' => 'other_bucket',
    'Key'    => 'file'
));
```

Why i can access to the other bucket when my policy only allow "facontroltest"

Comment: Delete this policy and I suspect you will find that the user can *still* access the other bucket, for a reason unrelated to this policy.

Comment: It's strange becuse the iam-user doesn't have other policy only this one, i dont know why don't work this policy, if i remove the policy he can't access to S3 from API